# I Want to take multi line input from user in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I want to take multi-line Input from users in python and this code take multi-line input from user put the output is only last line**

*I made this program which converts text into handwriting using `pywhatkit` library and I wants that user can give input in multi-lines and It take multi-lines but cannot print it only print last line.*

**Here I'm taking multi-line input from user**
[image]

**But in output it's printing only last line of my input**
[image]

```
from colorama import init
from termcolor import colored
import pywhatkit as kit
print("")   
init()
print(colored('Support me on Instagram: @shiva5harma ', 'white', 'on_red'))
print("")
print("Enter/Paste your content. Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z ( windows ) to save it.")
contents = []
while True:
    try:
        text = input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    contents.append(text)
print("")
print("-- Lcation Example: C:/User/owner/Desktop/image_name.png  --")
print("")
path=str(input("Enter Location where to store image\n"))
try:
  print("")
  print("I'm working on it Please Wait.......\n")
  kit.text_to_handwriting(text,path)
except:
   print("Error Occured")
finally:
   print("Your Image is ready !! Your will find your Image here\n",path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong parameter in this line:

```
kit.text_to_handwriting(text,path)
```

I believe it should be something like:

```
full_text = "\n".join(contents)  # Make one big string of all individual input lines
kit.text_to_handwriting(full_text,path)  # Use the new parameter
```

Comment: Yes, bro this is what I want Thank You!